# How to create new theme in magento 2 without parent theme delcartion?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, theme, parent-child-theme

What if i don't declare **parent theme** in **theme.xml** while creating **new theme** in magento 2? will the new theme work properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parent theme is necessary in Magento, if you don't want any parent theme, you can use blank theme as your parent theme:

```
<parent>Magento/blank</parent>
```

And this wont be an issue, your theme will work properly if you do this.

See [dev docs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html) for details

Comment: that means without giving parent node, new theme wont work? so its mandatory to add the parent node?

Comment: Yes it is mandatory. you can see dev docs of magento for more details: edited my answer

Answer (score 5):

We can create a new theme without depending any parent theme like Magento blank theme `vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/theme.xml`, the difficulty is you need to write all the look and feel changes from the scratch.

My suggestions is use blank theme as a parent theme, if you totally want to change any layout or build the styles from the scratch for the specific layout, use the [parent layout override concept](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-override.html).

I hope it helps.

Comment: yup true....we do not need to write code for all look and feel, that's why we use parent theme...

Comment: check my updated answer.